# Which is the Taraka Brahma Nama for kaliyuga as per scriptures?

Tags: mantras

'SrirAmarAmarAma' and the 'Harenkrishna' Mahamantra--both are referred to as Taraka-Brahma nAma. Which one is the TAraka-Brahma nAma for the kali yuga as per the scriptures?

Comment: What's the meaning of taraka brahma naama?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta The nAma chanting which one gets vision of God and liberation

Comment: @KrishnaShweta You have heard of taraka mantra that one gets if he passes away in Kashi? Taraka mantra is one which gives liberation!!!